# Solving Geometric Program

Tags: calculus

(Use a Calculator) Use geometric programming to solve the following program:

Minimine: $g(x) = \frac{1000}{xy} + 2x + 2y + xy$, $\forall x,y > 0$

I am a little confused on how to begin this program, can anyone give me any tips? Thanks!

Comment: Should the function be $g(x,y)?$

Comment: Hmm good point, I'm not sure, I was given g(x).

Comment: Without the $\forall y$ at the end, it could be that $y$ is a parameter and you are supposed to find the $x$ that minimizes $g(x)$.  But with it, I believe you are supposed to find both $x$ and $y$ that make $g(x,y)$ a minimum.

Comment: @RossMillikan Pretty sure I am supposed to use the AM-GM inequality here.

Answer (score 2):

This is exercise 26 from Chapter 2 , Peressini.
Solution is solve Dual geometric Programing: Maximize $$V(\delta)=(\frac{1000}{\delta_1})^{\delta_1}(\frac{2}{\delta_2})^{\delta_2}(\frac{2}{\delta_3})^{\delta_3}(\frac{1}{\delta_4})^{\delta_4}$$
Where $\delta = (\delta_1 ,\delta_2 ,\delta_3 ,\delta_4)$
with the conditions normality and ortogonality
$$ \left\{ \begin{array}{2}
\delta_1 +\delta_2+\delta_3+\delta_4 =1 \\[2ex] 
 -\delta_1 +\delta_2+0\delta_3+\delta_4 =0  \\[3ex]
-\delta_1 +0\delta_2+\delta_3+\delta_4 =0\end{array} \right. 
$$ 
And positivity condition $\delta_1>0,\delta_2>0,\delta_3>0,\delta_4>0$
Where the solution set from the system is $$K=\{(\delta_1 ,\delta_2 ,\delta_3 ,\delta_4) / \delta_2=\delta_3=1-2\delta_1 , \delta_4 = 3\delta_1-1, \frac{1}{3}<\delta_1<\frac{1}{2} \}$$ 
Now Maximize $$f(s)=(\frac{1000}{s})^{s}(\frac{2}{1-2s})^{1-2s}(\frac{2}{1-2s})^{1-2s}(\frac{1}{3s-1})^{3s-1}$$ on the interval $1/3<s<1/2$.Taking logs,we maximize
$$ u(s) =\ln f(s)=-s\ln \frac{s}{1000}-2(1-2s)\ln \frac{1-2s}{2}-(3s-1)\ln (3s-1)$$
Using Newton Method in $s_0 = 0.4$
$$s^{k+1}=s^k-\frac{u'(s^k)}{u''(s^k)}\approx s^k-\frac{\frac{u(s^k)-u(s^k-h)}{h}}{\frac{u(s^k+h)-2u(s^k)+u(s^k-h)}{h^2}}$$
with $h = 0.001$ and 100 iterations, $s^*=0.4394  \Rightarrow  u(s^*)=4.4405$
Then $$f(s^*) =e^{u(s^*)}=84.8197 $$
This is the minimun of $g(\mathbf{x})$

Answer (score 0):

Without a calculator, I would just use the fact that at the minimum you must have $\frac {\partial g(x,y)}{\partial x}=\frac {\partial g(x,y)}{\partial y}=0$  That will give you two equations in two unknowns.  The symmetry indicates that $x=y$ at the minimum (though you should check that).

My graphing calculator, [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimum%20of%201000%2Fx%2Fy%2B2x%2B2y%2Bxy), finds the minimum to be near $x=y=5.18284$  As it does not offer an exact result, I think you are just supposed to search around to find the minimum.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can also be solved numerically using [cvxpy's geometric programming capabilities](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/dgp/index.html), like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cvxpy as cp

x = cp.Variable(pos=True)
y = cp.Variable(pos=True)

constraints = []
objective   = 1000/x/y+2*x+2*y+x*y

prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(objective), constraints)

objval = prob.solve(gp=True)

print("Objective value = {0}".format(objval))
print("x value         = {0}".format(x.value))
print("y value         = {0}".format(y.value))
```

As output, this gives:

```
Objective value = 84.82073466127639
x value         = 5.182852109768804
y value         = 5.18285210938629
```